# Drawing ellipse inside rotated rectangle

Tags: iphone, drawrect

I am drawing rectangle with 4 points as below figure (I also have angle of the rectangle). How to draw ellipse inside the rotated rectangle?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would draw the rectangle (without rotation), then the ellipse (without rotation) and finally apply a rotation transformation to both of them. [Use CGAffineTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html).